# Why do I keep getting zero in my equation?

Tags: java, android, math, equation

I am trying to do some simple percents, and My results always is zero.

```
String taste = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("taste");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");

                Log.d("taste", rate);
                int rateNum = Integer.parseInt(rate);

                Log.d("taste", "rateNum is " + rateNum);

                int percent = rateNum / count;

                percent = percent * 100;

                Log.d("taste", "percent is " + percent);
```

The odd part is looking at my Log my rateNum and count Variables are both numbers and not zero:

```
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): count it:20
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): 13
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): rateNum is 13
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): percent is 0
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): 3
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): rateNum is 3
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): percent is 0
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): 3
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): rateNum is 3
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): percent is 0
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): 1
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): rateNum is 1
06-26 21:52:44.319: D/taste(11812): percent is 0
```

So I have no idea why I keep getting zero as my percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from mistakes with numerical type.

When you get rateNum, it is an `int`, as is count. Since int/int=int(truncating decimals), you are multiplying 0 by 100 to get 0.

The solution is as follows:

```
String taste = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("taste");
            String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");

            Log.d("taste", rate);
            double rateNum = Double.parseInt(rate);

            Log.d("taste", "rateNum is " + rateNum);

            double percent = rateNum / count;

            percent = percent * 100;

            Log.d("taste", "percent is " + percent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
int percent = (100*rateNum) / count;
```

or use floating point for the math.  Your value is being rounded down to zero and then never recovering.

Answer (score 0):

You are using int type to save the percent, so a number like 0.8 will be rounded to 0 at `int percent = rateNum / count;`

Use this instead

```
float percent = rateNum / count;
```